# Convert md5 in base64 in md5 of 32 characters with PHP

Tags: php, hash, md5

I have an example:

```
Md5 base64: wPE2JkrsTJxF+KbSDApwYQ==
Md5 using md5_file: c0f136264aec4c9c45f8a6d20c0a7061
```

how convert the firts md5 in the second md5?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`base64_decode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.base64-decode.php) gets you from base64 back to binary, and then [`bin2hex`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.bin2hex.php) converts that to hex:

```
$var = "wPE2JkrsTJxF+KbSDApwYQ==";
echo bin2hex (base64_decode ($var));
// prints c0f136264aec4c9c45f8a6d20c0a7061
```